# Wordpress session is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I'm trying to understand why the wordpress session doesnt't work.

When I write `print_r($_SESSION);` it returns me empty array.

I also tried with `$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();`, but it returns me error -
There was a critical error on your website.

What is the right way to access the session in wordpress? Thanks!

Comment: FYI the $_SESSION was not used by Wordpress

Comment: Are you making sure to have a session_start(); ?

Comment: Sessions aren't enabled in wordpress by default so you have to start maually.

Comment: Ok, I added this code in functions.php

`function register_my_session()
{
  if( !session_id() )
  {
    session_start();
  }
}

add_action('init', 'register_my_session');`

In my plugin I try to access the session by 

`$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
var_dump($wp_session);`

The message again is "There was a critical error on your website".

Comment: Check, please server logs.

Comment: I installed WP Session Manager plugin and now there is no critical error, but wp_session is still empty. Is it possible session always to be empty?

Answer (score 2):

[WP Session Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/) plugin is abadoned as I can see. So if your added

```
function register_my_session()             
{                                          
    if (!session_id()) {                   
        session_start();                   
    }                                      
}                                          
                                           
add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
```

After this you can [directly use](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/#how%20do%20i%20add%20session%20variables%3F) [$_SESSION variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

```
$_SESSION['user_name'] = 'User Name';        
echo $_SESSION['user_name']; // 'User Name'
```

Comment: Yes, It's possible to add a new data into the session, but my question is it normal session to be completely empty in the beginning? I think there shoud be some data in the session before I add something else.

Comment: Yes, it's normal. Wordpress internally don't use PHP session.

Comment: This works for me and it works without the `if (!session_id()) {`. Just calling `session_start();` every time seems to be fine.